# Python 3 Pandas Timestamp Date Parse

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime, timestamp

I have some time series data from an API request and when I am doing some data wrangling this error pops up below. The data wrangling is just some simple  Pandas series math (not shown).

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*

But when I save the data to a CSV:

```
elecMeter_df.to_csv('C:\\Python Scripts\\elecMeter_df.csv', sep=',', header=True, index=True, na_rep='N/A')
```

And then parse the dates on a read_CSV:

```
elecMeter_dfCSV = pd.read_csv('C:\\Python Scripts\\elecMeter_df.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

I do not get the original error described above.. Why is that? Am I getting the error because the time stamp is a string and I need to convert into an integer format?

When I get the error, the index is in this format:

```
print(elecMeter_df.index)
```

[image]

But when read the CSV file and Parse the date column (No error in the data wrangling processes, the index is in this format: (no Chicago Time zone reference)

```
print(elecMeter_df.index)
```

[image]

Any help/tips that can be explained to me about time stamps and why this error happens would be greatly appreciated. Utilimetely I am trying to not have to use the read/write CSV process, but if its the only method to not get any errors Ill just stick with that!

Comment: what is `type()` of the data you are trying to parse?  what is the parsing operation (e.g.,is it `pd.to_datetime()`), and are you having trouble [working with time zones](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones).  Also, please don't paste output, put it in a code block.

Comment: what command is causing that error? PS the only difference i see is that one index is TZ aware (America/Chicago) and the second is not

Comment: @Henry I think the CSV workaround is just ignoring the TZ offset, which is what is messing up your datetime conversion, because it's usually `-0500` instead of `-05:00` -- can you assume that all your data is on Chicago time, or do you require a TZ aware solution

Comment: Ok sorry about the snip of the output :) Ill remember not to do that in the future... MetaDataFrame appears to be the type

Comment: AttributeError: 'MetaDataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: @Henry that's because you should be using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) not trying to do `df.to_datetime` please read the doc.

Comment: @HenryHub, can you post the following output __as text__: `print(elecMeter_df.index[:3])` for both cases?

Comment: DatetimeIndex(['2017-10-01 00:00:11.556000-05:00',
               '2017-10-01 00:15:14.962000-05:00',
               '2017-10-01 00:30:20.208000-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/Chicago]', freq=None)

Comment: When I do the pd.to_datetime(elecMeter_df), this happens - ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: Im using the latest download of the anaconda Jupiter note books

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what code you are running to generate that error. However the time stamp probably needs to be converted from a string to a date time. Try using pd.to_datetime, additionally you can specify the format (list of options and meanings are provided below). The example I used for the format is year-month-day hour-minutes.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M)



%a  Locale’s abbreviated weekday name.
%A  Locale’s full weekday name.      
%b  Locale’s abbreviated month name.     
%B  Locale’s full month name.
%c  Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.   
%d  Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].    
%f  Microsecond as a decimal number [0,999999], zero-padded on the left
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].    
%I  Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].    
%j  Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].   
%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].   
%M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].      
%p  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
%S  Second as a decimal number [00,61].
%U  Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week)
%w  Weekday as a decimal number [0(Sunday),6].   
%W  Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week)
%x  Locale’s appropriate date representation.    
%X  Locale’s appropriate time representation.    
%y  Year without century as a decimal number [00,99].    
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.   
%z  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.
%Z  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).    
%%  A literal '%' character.
```

Comment: this does not answer the question